# Encrypt multimedia files with GPG

Tags: encryption, gpg

Is it possible to encrypt pictures and other files like audio etc with GPG? If yes then how to? If not then why not?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. `gpg` normally handles files as binary and you don't have to do anything special to encrypt pictures or audio.

```
gpg -c yourfile.mp3
```

for symmetric encryption and

```
gpg -e yourfile.mp3
```

to encrypt with your (pregenerated) private key.